# Message processig - should I use JMS?

Tags: java, spring, architecture, jms

I'm developing a 'WS oriented' application basing on Spring/CXF/Oracle DB. Now, I stuck with some architectural consideration about right approach to organize message processing (already stored in db).

**Briefly, process looks as follows:**

(A) Get the message from client -> Validate -> Store -> Send reposponse

(B) Process -> Update data

**I consider two general approaches for part B of the process:**

1) Use JMS queue

Just after validation and storing incoming message details in DB publish a message to the JSM queue. On the other side define cosumer which will retrieve the message and do the processing

2) Fetch data to be processed

Manually fetch data from with db and process it.

**Additional facts:**

- The processing won't be compute-intensive, so for new I dont think that work distribution will be needed (all in single JVM).
- All data in single db schema

So, I'm interested what are key factors to choose JMS in such case?

Comment: I would suggest [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/). Just define the component and channels, then later when needed you can always switch to JMS (or another transport for your messags/triggers).

Answer (score 0):

JMS would be a better approach. In positive scenario, approach #2 works as well. But JMS would provide you some in-built capability, specially for failed case. Though internally JMS would be using a DB-based persistent storage; it would provide a better interface to communicate that data.

For example, you could configure an error queue to track all the messages, whose processing failed.

It would also provide you scalable architecture, where some other app (in future) could starts consuming your message and process.

Reliable: Due to asynchronous messaging, all the pieces don’t need to be up for the application to function as a whole.

Flexible : Think of scenario, in which you might want to process certain type of data before all other (prioritization). JMS would provide more better approach than tweaking logic in a program.